# How can I write this code more efficiently with DRY concept?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dry

This is a piece of a JavaScript code for an HTML form. I want to be more efficient and not write the same line more than once; is this possible in the code below?

```js
function resetOptions(location)
{   
    if (location=='country') 
    {   
        removeOptions(selected_address_zone)
        removeOptions(selected_address_region)
        removeOptions(selected_address_city)
        removeOptions(selected_address_area)
    }
    else if (location=='zone')
    {
        removeOptions(selected_address_region)
        removeOptions(selected_address_city)
        removeOptions(selected_address_area)
    }
    else if (location=='region')
    {
        removeOptions(selected_address_city)
        removeOptions(selected_address_area)
    }
    else
    {
        removeOptions(selected_address_area)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is crying out for a look-up table, like `{ country: [ selected_address_zone, ... ], zone: [ ... ] }` where you can just jump tot the list you need to remove.

Comment: Repeating doesn't mean that in all cases line called for same reason. You should dry out only lines which called for same reason. In your case if I move `selected_address_area` outside of `if .. else`, because it is called for all cases, then I will have a problem next time when I introduce new `else if` or I need to change what is removing for zone option.

Comment: "*and not repeat the same line more than once*" Just out of curiosity, do you mean this? Or do you mean you do not want to *write* the same line more than once?

Comment: @TylerH removeOptions(selected_address_area) has been written three times I wanted to write this only once

Answer (score 4):

You could rewrite with a switch statement without breaks. By doing this, if the location is a country, for instance, it will execute the cases below it until it finds a break.

```
  switch(location): {
    case: 'country': 
        removeOptions(selected_address_zone);
    case 'zone': 
        removeOptions(selected_address_region);
    case 'region':
        removeOptions(selected_address_city);
    default:
        removeOptions(selected_address_area);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set variables for the arguments passed in the removeOptions() function at the top of your function.

You could then adjust the arguments according to your function parameters.

Would be helpful to see the removeOptions() function and its parameters.